# Android Can I use C++ library via JNI interface and put my app in the marketplace?

Tags: android

Thats it.  I am looking to use a C/C++ Library in my Android app.  So JNI to access the library functions.

So 1) Can JNI be used inside an Android app.
   2) Any restriction in putting my hybrid app Java/JNI android app into the android marketplace?  Any restrictions on the inclusion of C/C++ libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JNI all you want. There are no restrictions. I have an app with a JNI library in the market, no problemo.

At some point, maybe you'll want to compile your JNI library for both ARM and x86. But not now, the few existing x86 Android devices do not get the "Google Experience" treatment.